# aframe - Quality loss in VR-mode on iPhone 6 with iOS 10.2

Tags: aframe, webvr

I've read that there is a bug on iOS which produces low resolution for aframe scenes in VR-mode: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1873

I'm using an iPhone6 with iOS 10.2 and still have this issue. I've also added the recommended fix like followed, but the resolution is not usable...

```
<head>
...    
<script>
    window.WebVRConfig = {
        BUFFER_SCALE: 1,
        CARDBOARD_UI_DISABLED: true,
        ROTATE_INSTRUCTIONS_DISABLED: true,
        TOUCH_PANNER_DISABLED: true,
        MOUSE_KEYBOARD_CONTROLS_DISABLED: true,
        FORCE_ENABLE_VR: true
    };
</script>
<script src="components/aframe.js"></script>
</head>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a fix for that? Here's the demo:
http://dev.thomasveit.com/vr/

Comment: Still up to investigate in the WebVR polyfill. Probably about time to file an issue and/or ask Boris.